# Output block size with AES

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, racket

I'm trying to use the Racket [Crypto library](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/package-source/vyzo/crypto.plt/2/3/planet-docs/manual/index.html) to [encrypt](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/package-source/vyzo/crypto.plt/2/3/planet-docs/manual/index.html#%28def._%28/home/vyzo/data/src/mzcrypto/dist/crypto/cipher..ss._encrypt%29%29) blocks of 16 bytes with a 16-byte key. I'm expecting to have a 16-bytes output block but I get a 32-byte one.
A 15-byte input block give a 16-bit output.

```
#lang racket

(require (planet vyzo/crypto))

(bytes-length (encrypt cipher:aes-128-ecb
                       (string->bytes/latin-1 "0123456789ABCDEF") ; 16-byte key
                       (make-bytes 16) ; IV
                       (string->bytes/latin-1 "0123456789ABCDEF"))) ; 16-byte data
; -> 32

(bytes-length (encrypt cipher:aes-128-ecb
                       (string->bytes/latin-1 "0123456789ABCDEF") ; 16-byte key
                       (make-bytes 16)
                       (string->bytes/latin-1 "0123456789ABCDE"))) ; 15-byte data
; -> 16
```

Am I wrong somewhere? Is this due to padding?

Note: I'm aware of the problems with ECB mode, My goal is to implement CBC mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it's because of the padding. Unfortunately the API of the [vyzo/crypto lib](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/display.ss?package=crypto.plt&owner=vyzo) doesn't allow you to easily disable padding (and rightly so, see Caveat below).

**How to disable the padding**

However, based on this [Thread on the Racket users mailing list](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2012-April/051748.html), you could disable the padding like this:

```
#lang racket

(require (planet vyzo/crypto) (planet vyzo/crypto/util))

(define (cipher-encrypt-unpadded type key iv)
  (lambda (ptext)
    (let ((octx (cipher-encrypt type key iv #:padding #f)))
      (bytes-append (cipher-update! octx ptext)
                    (cipher-final! octx)))))

(define (cipher-decrypt-unpadded type key iv)
  (lambda (ctext)
    (let ((ictx (cipher-decrypt type key iv #:padding #f)))
      (bytes-append (cipher-update! ictx ctext)
                    (cipher-final! ictx)))))

; bytes-> bytes
; convenience function for encryption
(define enc-aes-128-ecb-unpadded 
   (cipher-encrypt-unpadded cipher:aes-128-ecb 
                            (string->bytes/latin-1 "0123456789ABCDEF"); 16-byte key
                            (make-bytes 16)))

; bytes -> bytes
; convenience function for decryption       
(define dec-aes-128-ecb-unpadded 
   (cipher-decrypt-unpadded cipher:aes-128-ecb 
                            (string->bytes/latin-1 "0123456789ABCDEF"); 16-byte key
                            (make-bytes 16)))

(define message (string->bytes/latin-1 "0123456789ABCDEF")) ; 16-byte data

(bytes-length (enc-aes-128-ecb-unpadded message))
; -> 16


(dec-aes-128-ecb-unpadded (enc-aes-128-ecb-unpadded message))
; -> #"0123456789ABCDEF"
```

This worked well on my machine. Also, switching to CBC mode is trivial.

**Caveat**

When you disable padding, your messages have to have a length that is a multiple of the block size. For AES128 that is an exact multiple of 16 Bytes. Otherwise the function will blow up in your face:

```
(enc-aes-128-ecb-unpadded (string->bytes/latin-1 "too short!"))
EVP_CipherFinal_ex: libcrypto error: data not multiple of block length [digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:101183626]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all input is being padded to the *next* block boundary.  That means that a 16 byte input will be padded to the next boundary at 32 bytes.  If all your input is going to be exact block sizes, then you could turn off padding.  If the input can end in the middle of a block then you will have to leave padding switched on.

If you are going to be using CBC mode, then you might need to think about authentication as well.  If you do need it, then HMAC is probably the easiest to get started with.